# Subshell MySQL-query in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ubuntu, subshell

I'm trying to set variable in the cycle in Ubuntu bash, which is getting recordset from database, but this variable is setting to its previous value.
Here is a code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PREV_FILE_PATH="127"

while true
do
    echo "$PREV_FILE_PATH"
    mysql -h$DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME --skip-column-names --default-character-set=UTF8  -e "here is a query" | while read "here is getting variables from recordset";

    do

    PREV_FILE_PATH="777"

    done

done
```

And this code prints every time:

> 127
>   127
>   127

But whe I replaced this block-:

`mysql -h$DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME --skip-column-names --default-character-set=UTF8  -e "here is a query" | while read "here is getting variables from recordset";`

with just `while true` and break at the end of cycle it works fine and prints:

> 127
>   777
>   777
>   777

Script creates some subshell and running that MySQL query in that subshell. So what should I do to make script change that variable?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted the issue is due to the creation of a subshell which is being caused by piping the output of the `mysql` command to the `while` loop. A simple example:

```
PREV_FILE_PATH=127
echo test | while read _; do
   PREV_FILE_PATH=777
done
echo $PREV_FILE_PATH
# output: 127
```

Since you're using BASH you can move the `mysql` command from being a pipe to a [substituted process](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) fed to the `while` loop via STDIN [redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/redircb.html). Using the previous simple example:

```
PREV_FILE_PATH=127
while read _; do
   PREV_FILE_PATH=777
done < <(echo test)
echo $PREV_FILE_PATH
# output: 777
```

So to fix your code, you will want to move your `mysql` command in the same fashion that I moved the `echo` command above:

```
while read "here is getting variables from recordset"
do
   PREV_FILE_PATH="777"
done < <(mysql -h$DB_HOST -u $DB_USER [..remaining options..])
```

Note that process substitution via `<()` is a BASH-ism and isn't POSIX compliant.